# Is Amazon EC2 irrelevant?

Tags: discussion

There are a lot of questions tagged with [amazon-ec2](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2) or [amazon-aws](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-aws) that seem completely irrelevant to EC2, they're generic questions regarding servers that just happen to be running on EC2, quite a few of them could replace EC2 with 'Rackspace' or 'Softlayer' or 'Whatever Provider Inc.' and the question would still be the same, is it appropriate to un-tag these questions?

Examples;

- [cannot load such file -- OpenSSL (LoadError)](https://serverfault.com/questions/366138/cannot-load-such-file-openssl-loaderror)
- [Is there a GUI alternative to Putty SSH for transferring files?](https://serverfault.com/questions/366481/is-there-a-gui-alternative-to-putty-ssh-for-transferring-files)
- [Ubuntu - how to determine cause for server swaps?](https://serverfault.com/questions/367200/ubuntu-how-to-determine-cause-for-server-swaps)

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes questions are tagged with [ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) or [centos](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/centos) even though they have nothing to do with Ubuntu or CentOS.  However, knowing which distribution the user is using allows the answer to contain distro-specific instructions like using `apt-get` instead of `yum` and `/etc/apache2/` instead of `/etc/httpd/`.

The Amazon-related tags could allow the answer to contain Amazon-specific instructions in the same way.

Answer (score 9):

If the tag has zero relevance to the question feel free to remove the tag (and/or add more appropriate ones).

Unfortunately (and especially for new users) tagging is more of a "Throw everything at the question and pray someone sees it" than a surgical "I've isolated the problem to these items" kind of thing. Fixing lousy tagging is definitely a Good Thing.

Answer (score 4):

I'd rather see the tagging fixed on individual questions rather than nuking the tag.